Is it correct to say: "We were eager to know what would happen in year 2050"?
Is it correct to say the following?

We were eager to know what would happen in year 2050.

In the main clause, the sentence uses past simple tense, but in the object clause which tense should be used-future tense or past tense?
Which one is correct?

We were eager to know what would happen in year 2050.
We were eager to know what will happen in year 2050.


Neither strikes me as glaringly wrong, but I would say 'in the year 2050'.

It's a matter of perspective. If 20 years ago you were discussing what would happen in 2050 based on trends at the time (which may no longer be relevant), use 1. If you think your discussion is still valid, then 2.

@StuartF Although in the second case you can also say "We are eager" or "We have been eager".

(Also, 1 would be the only option if this is a bit of sci-fi set in the year 2060! So no, there's nothing inherently wrong with it.)

Your (1) is idiomatic; would is used as a “backshifted” form of will. Compare we are eager to know what will happen with we were eager to know what would happen.
